# Simplify $\Pr(Z\ge P(X))$ with $Z\sim N(0,1)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, gaussian-integral

Consider a discrete rv $X$ with probability function $p(x)$ and an independent $Z\sim N(0,1)$

I am trying to write the probability
\begin{align}
\Pr(Z\ge p(X))
\end{align}
as a single Q-function $Q(x)\triangleq \Pr(Z\ge x)$. A similar upper bound can also be useful, but it should take into consideration the probability function $p(x)$ (and not the trivial one with minimum over $p(x)$).

I initially thought that $\Pr(Z\ge p(X))\le Q(E[p(X)])$ due to the convexity of $Q(x)$ on $x>0$, but an answer below shows that I used Jensen's in the incorrect direction and the opposite is true, i.e.
\begin{align}
\Pr(Z\ge p(X))\ge Q(E[p(X)]).
\end{align}

Comment: Since $Z\sim N(0,1)$ the probability ${\rm Pr}(Z\ge\alpha)$ is $1-\int_0^\alpha \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}\,dx$ ( well known how to calculate ). Now plug in $\alpha=P(X)$.

Comment: No @KurtG., $P(X)$ is a random variable and $\alpha$ is a realization.

Comment: You wrote "Consider a discrete rv $X$ with $P(X=x)$..." I know what $X$ is. What is $P$ ? What is $P(X)$ ?

Comment: Writing $p()$ for the pmf of $X$, we have $P(Z\ge p(X))=E[P(Z\ge p(X)\mid X)]=E[Q(p(X))]=\sum_x p(x)Q(p(x)).$ This suggests two possible [approximations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables) that you might want to investigate: (1) $E[Q(p(X))]\approx Q(E[p(X)])=Q(\sum_x p(x)^2)$, and (2)  $E[Q(p(X))]\approx Q(p(\hat x)),$ where $\hat x$ is the value nearest to $E[X]$ in the support of $X$.

Comment: (I've assumed $Q(x):= P(Z\ge x)$, and that your "$P(X)$" is $p(X)$, where $p()$ is the pmf of $X$.)

Comment: @r.e.s. Thanks, my question is about your first approximation: is it an upper bound? I hope to be able to show it via Jensen's inequality since $1\ge p(x)\ge0$.

Comment: I have no idea what you are really trying to ask. But if $\Phi(x) = P(Z \leq x),$ then you want the random variable $1 - \Phi(p(X)).$ This is a discrete random variable, it takes the value $1 - \Phi(a)$ with probabilty $\sum_{x:p(x) = a} p(x).$ (It seems you are looking for an upper bound, obviously $1$ works. You can use the typical inequality $1 - \Phi(a) \sim a^{-1} n(a),$ where $n$ is the standard Gaussian density to obtain a much sharper bound.)

Comment: @WilliamM. Could you pls elaborate? do you mean $\Pr[Z\ge p(X)]\le \sum \frac1{p(x)}Q(p(x))$?

Comment: Are you aware $P(Z > p(X))$ is a random variable? Namely, it is $1 - \Phi(p(X)).$ As such, if you bound the function $t \mapsto 1 - \Phi(t)$ you are done. The supremum and infimum of this function is $1$ and $0,$ resp. But if $X$ only takes finitely many values, then you only consider finitely many values of $1 - \Phi(t),$ there is not much else to say.

Comment: It is not a rv, see the suggested answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $p()$ for the pmf of $X$ and defining $Q(z):= P(Z\ge z),$ we have
$$\begin{align}P(Z\ge p(X))
&=E[P(Z\ge p(X)\mid X)]\\[2mm]
&=E[Q(p(X))]\\[2mm]
&\ge Q\left(E[p(X)]\right)\quad\text{by Jensen's inequality}\\[2mm]
&\ge Q\left(\sum_x p(x)^2\right).
\end{align}$$

Note that Jensen's inequality applies because $p(X)\ge 0$, and $Q()$ is convex on $[0,\infty)$.

Now $Z\ge p(X)\implies Z\ge p_{\inf}$, where $p_{\inf}=\inf\{p(x): p(x)>0, x\in\mathbb R\};$  hence, $P(Z\ge p(X)) \le P(Z\ge p_{\inf})=Q(p_{\inf})\le Q(0)={1\over 2},$ giving the following bounds:
$$\color{blue}{Q\left(\sum_x p(x)^2\right)\quad \le\quad P\left(Z\ge p(X)\right)\quad \le\quad Q(p_{\inf})}.$$

**NB**: It also follows that  $\sum_x p(x)^2\ge p_\inf$ for *any* discrete distribution.

---

Aside from the above "trivial" upper bound, here is another ...

[Samford (1953)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-24/issue-1/Some-Inequalities-on-Mills-Ratio-and-Related-Functions/10.1214/aoms/1177729093.full) proves that $\forall t\ge 0,\ Q(t)\le B(t),$ where $B(t)={4\phi(t)\over 3t+\sqrt{8+t^2}}$, and $\phi(t)={1\over\sqrt{2\pi}}\,e^{-t^2/2}.$ Therefore,

$$P(Z\ge p(X))=\sum_x p(x) Q(p(x))\le\sum_x p(x)\, B(p(x)).$$

**Example** (binary case, with $p(x)\in\{p, 1-p\}$):

$$\begin{align}P(Z\ge p(X))&= p\,Q(p) + (1-p)\,Q(1-p)\\
&\le p\,B(p)+(1-p)\,B(1-p)\end{align}$$

Here's a picture showing this upper bound as the dashed line (red) and $P(Z\ge p(X))$ as the solid line (blue):

[image]

Comment: Thanks $r.e.s., but this shows that my guess is a lower bound, and the objective is to find an upper bound.

Comment: @Morad Your upper bound guess involves $E[X]$, but this lower bound involves $E[p(X)].$ (You've mis-stated it in your latest edit.)

Comment: I truly appreciate but the question explicitly mentions that a tighter bound rather than the trivial "min" is needed. I will accept any answer with any non-trivial bound even for the binary case.